# PowerBi Desktop: Creating simple line chart

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I want to plot a simple time-series, containing 20 values and their respective timestamp:

[image]

However, I cannot drag-and-drop the "value" column in the "Values" section of the visualisation. If I try, it gets reformatted as "Count of value" (whatever that means). In the dropdown menu I cannot select to just display the values, just a range of other options such as min, max, sum ... etc.[image]

As a result of the "Count of value" selection, the plot just says "20".

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

The "Do not summarize" option is active:

[image]

Comment: Can you check by Right Click on the Value column in the Visualization pane? There you will get different aggregation options you wants to apply. If no aggregation is required, you can simply select the option - Do Not Summarize.

Comment: made some edits!

Comment: The graph will only show an aggregate. If you select SUM, and you only have one entry for each date, then it will show the expected result (i.e. the value), since it is only summing one value.

Comment: the graph only summed it up, because of the date hierarchy. check out my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the date that was put in the "Axis" field. It summed up the values of the same day, since it somehow did not consider the times, just day, month and year.

I was able to resolve the issue by creating a new column, then inputting this to the diagram:

[image]

[image]

If someone would provide an answer containing a solution without having to create an extra column, I will mark it as correct answer.

Comment: If you add time column to Axis and value to Values, you will get the same output you are getting using your new column time2.